# Is there a name for crosswords where the surface of the vertical clues resemble the solutions to the horizontal and vice versa?

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, puzzle-identification

Occasionally a crossword (often cryptic ones) would have a twist to them, such as being a ['nina'](https://www.crosswordunclued.com/2009/10/what-is-nina.html):

> A Nina is a special feature of the crossword grid: a word, words or phrase hidden within a pattern of cells in the completed grid.

There're other 'twists' such as when a crossword is ['pangramic'](https://www.crosswordunclued.com/2009/09/pangram.html):

> In cryptic crosswords, a "pangram" is a grid that has at least one occurrence of each letter of the English alphabet.

So, now I've introduced these twists, hopefully my request to name a different twist makes sense. The twist I'm looking for the name of is where the surface of the horizontal clues contain a theme matched by the solutions to the vertical clues, and vice versa (the vertical surfaces match the theme of the horizontal answers).

As an example would be, as an across clue with a dog surface and cat solution:

> Spot (marking a location), following it's master, is found tailless on island (4)

> MANX: X is a spot (implying a common Dog's name 'Spot') marked on treasure maps, after MAN (the aforementioned dog's master), clueing the Manx of [Manx Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manx_cat)

And then a down clue example could be, with a cat surface and dog solution:

> Big cat meal sounds like it's from German town (10)

> LEONBERGER: ~(Lion Burger) is a breed of [dog breed named after a german town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonberger)

---

Is this a known type of crossword theme? I would like to know before I start making one myself.